# LXC - How to assign public ip to a single container

Tags: centos7, lxc

Here is my setup.

- **Host Machine**-[Ubuntu 16.04][185.82.xx.xx]

  - Container1 [10.0.8.9]
  - Container2 [10.0.8.100]
  - Container3 [10.0.8.101]
  - *`Container4`* [10.0.8.102]

All are working great.

Now, I purchased another `dedicated IP` for my server. I have required information for my new IP [`ip_address`, `gateway` and `netmask`]

I want to assign my new dedicated IP to `Container 4`. I tried to set the required information in Centos' related networking files, but it did not work. Container has no access to internet right now.

This is the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` file:

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=185.82.x.x
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
HOSTNAME=LXC_NAME
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
DHCP_HOSTNAME=`hostname`
```

And this is the `/etc/sysconfig/network` file:

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=LXC_NAME
GATEWAY=185.82.x.1
```

What can I do to make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a bridge on eth0 and add this single VM to the brigde. You will then be able to setup public ip in the container.

The second option is to configure 1:1 NAT and assign the IP to the host itself.

**Update**

Before you start, please ensure you have bridge-utils package installed on your system. Feel free to follow this guide in order to create a bridge: http://www.itechlounge.net/2013/01/linux-how-to-create-a-bridge-interface-on-rhel-centos/

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can you me show me an example for creating and adding a bridge; any kind of help d be great.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a guide.

Comment: I think i broke network settings while setting bridge up. I need to add a new bridge on host machine[ubuntu] next to eth0 , right?